# Php subarrays code adds extra values

Tags: php, arrays

This is the php code:

```
$slavesites = array(
    'Category1' => array('Anchor1', 'http://www.test1.com'),
    'Category2' => array('Anchor2', 'http://www.test2.com')
);

foreach($slavesites as $category => $slavesite){
    echo $category;
    foreach($slavesite as $anc => $url){             
        echo $anc.'<br>'; 
        echo $url.'<br>'; 
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the code, i get a "0" and "1":

```
Category10 **--- WHERE DOES THE 0 COME FROM?**
Anchor1
1 **---- WHERE DOES THE 1 COME FROM?**
http://www.test1.com
Category20 --- WHERE DOES THE 0 COME FROM?
Anchor2
1 ---- WHERE DOES THE 1 COME FROM?
http://www.test2.com
```

Ty!:)
Hope you can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

second foreach iterates over array without proper indices set. that way default indices (0,1,2,...) are used and hence the number in output.

e.g. actually your definition is like this:

```
$slavesites = array(
    'Category1' => array(0 => 'Anchor1', 1 => 'http://www.test1.com'),
    'Category2' => array(0 => 'Anchor2', 1 => 'http://www.test2.com')
);
```

you should use 'list' instead of 'foreach' in the inner loop:

```
list($anc, $url) = $slavesite;
```

Comment: It worked, ty so much.... I have one question tho, is instead of "Category1" and "Category2" values I use the same value, my first foreach loop will show online the second array's data and not the first... this is imp for me becouse sometimes I have the same category for multiple sites.

Comment: you mean like this?  array('Cat' => array(...), 'Cat' => array(...)) ?

Comment: yeah, definitely you mean that. bad luck this isn't work out way. structure your data like this, if you want to handle add equal categories names:  array(  'Category' => array( array('Name', 'http://url/'), array('Name2', 'http://url2/')), 'Category2' => ... );

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop through your array like that, you have to store the elements as key-value pairs:

```
$slavesites = array(
  'Category1' => array('Anchor1' => 'http://www.test1.com'),
  'Category2' => array('Anchor2' => 'http://www.test2.com')
);
```

The `0` and the `1` are shown because you don't have keys defined and it therefores uses numerical keys.